# Summon an item frame with custom item which have data on it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on a map. I met a trouble where I want to summon an item frame with some item which have data on it. Like example: Dragon Head, Chiseled Quartz Block. They don't have its own id, they need to add a data tag.

This is what I have tried:

```
/summon ItemFrame 2019 32 1060 {Facing:3,Item:{id:0397:5,Count:1}}
```

I know ids doesn't work on 1.9 so how to summon them? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Damage` tag holds the metadata value of the item:

```
/summon ItemFrame 2019 32 1060 {Facing:3,Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:5,Count:1}}
```

Since 1.8, you should not have been using numerical IDs in NBT data. Since 1.7, using numerical IDs in command syntax presented you with a warning to not use name IDs.